# firefox addon sdk - setting an SSL certificate for https requests

Tags: javascript, ssl-certificate, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a firefox addon, and I need to make https calls. I am given an **SSL certificate information** (Serial Number, SHA1 Fingerprint, andMD5 Fingerprint). When I try to use the Request module from my main.js I always get a status of **0**. I tried the Request module with other http requests which are not secured and it works fine.

So I assume that the 0 status has to do with the SSL certificate.

Although I try to simulate the same requests using **Dev-HTTP-Client** google chrome plugin and it **works fine** and I can get proper responses from the https server.

I am not sure but I think I need to use the chrome module Cc["@mozilla.org/security/... to make this work.

If you can guide me with the proper steps to setup the SSL certificate information from inside the addon that would be great

Comment: I don't see any existing docs on this related to extensions. I'd suggest dropping by #extdev on irc.mozilla.org or posting to the dev-extensions mailing list: https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/dev-extensions

Comment: Since Chrome can talk with the server, the issue can't be the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to verify a cert manually and continue with the request. Instead you need to add an override on error yourself and retry.

1. Attempt to make a regular `XMLHttpRequest` via `nsIXMLHttpRequest`. There is enough code and samples around on SO and Google describing how to do it. The `requests` module won't do, as it hides some necessary details.
2. Implement `nsIBadCertListener2` and stuff it into `req.channel.notificationCallbacks` (might want to preserve the original callbacks).
3. If your `.notifyCertProblem()` get called, that means the cert did not verify. Now it's up to you to verify the cert with your seeded fingerprint (and serial).
4. If your seeded infos match, [add a cert override](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/security/manager/ssl/public/nsICertOverrideService.idl) (that won't work for STS hosts, of course)
5. Re-spin the request after adding the override, as the first request already got canceled as soon as it hit notifyCertProblem().

Most of the stuff is neatly demonstrated in [ErrorPage.jsm](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/b2g/components/ErrorPage.jsm#22) of Boot2Gecko (still applies to all other mozilla powered products). That's a cross reference, so click around ;)
Of course, you'll need to use the [`chrome`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) module.

I should mention that it is deliberate that I'm not giving a *complete* copy-pasta code solution, only all required pointers, as it is my opinion that a person should be capable enough to work with what I provided, or don't touch security subsystems in the first place.